# Git Hub Questions

Tags: git, github, repository

I have two github questions:

1. Does all code need to be made public? (i.e., can we keep our code private on github, or do we have to share it with the world?)
2. Is it necessary to use a command-line interface? (I prefer not)

**Edit: Regarding question #2, I am running Windows.**

Comment: Just for clarification, git is open source and requires no sign up or money to have private respitories(it is just a version tracker).  Github is social coding site based off of the version tracker github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can be private, but it costs money in that case.

I know there is a Mac graphical interface made specifically for GitHub. I imagine that any of the graphical interfaces for Git can work with GitHub too however.

Answer (score 1):

1. No - You can have private repositories, although I believe that there is a monthly charge if you don't want public repositories.
2. No - No, you can use a web interface among many other custom options. If you're on a mac, my favorite is [GitBox](http://gitboxapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Reg first question, you can keep repo's private but you need to pay monthly fee for that (base one is around USD7 & can store 5 repos). If you want free, then no way other than to keep public.